# trying to up keycloak with docker but it's not starting . Operation ("add") failed - address:

Tags: docker, oauth, keycloak

```
05:49:02,840 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:86)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
        at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:451)
        at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:404)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem?
I have the same problem, and see there might be an answer behind the redhat pay-wall https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5064741

Comment: Were any of you able to get this working?

Comment: Can you add more information about your setup? What keycloak and database version are you using? Are there more errors in the log?
I had this error amongst others and it turned out to be a database issue.

Comment: The log that you provided isn't full. Usually `Operation ("add") failed` is the last message, but stack trace is on top. You need to read stack trace first, it could be any reason

Answer (score 7):

I had this error while trying to run Keycloak in a docker-compose setup. My problem was caused because Keycloak was unable to connect to the database container. In fact keycloak startup logs were complaining about database connection problems few lines prior the error "... Operation ("add") failed ..."

Comment: can you show me docker-compose file for keycloak because i have the same problem i cannot run container when add MySql data base with keycloak

Comment: @abdalrhman-alkraien ensure your share the db password in both `environment:` of the database and keycloak service.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why the Keycloak start-up might fail is that you missed to [enable the upload scripts flag](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#using-keycloak-administration-console-to-upload-scripts).

The flag is deprecated and is normally only necessary if you want to do a realm import via the admin interface but in my case it was also necessary to enable the flag if I wanted to start-up Keycloak with an import file. Otherwise the same exception would be thrown that you provided in the original question.

The start-up param for enabling the flag is: `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled`

A small disclaimer here. As the documentation states this flag should not be continuously enabled. So just enable it for the initial import and persist your realm configuration in an external database.

Comment: Thanks, that was an extremely misleading error

Answer (score 0):

For me, running the container in a docker-compose situation, adding the `DB_VENDOR` env variable helped:

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_VENDOR: h2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using this code from the repository and tutorial:[Tutorial angular keykloak spring boot](https://wkrzywiec.medium.com/step-by-step-guide-how-integrate-keycloak-with-angular-application-d96b05f7dfdd)

I did docker-compose up without finishing the tutorial, And got the same error. After reading more i saw that i was missing the installation of the libraries haha. So this command solved my problems.

```
npm install keycloak-angular keycloak-js
```

Comment: Where did you run this command ? inside of container?